# Is there a GPO or registry tweak to show taskbar buttons on taskbar where windows is open?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry, windows-10

Is there a registry tweak or a group policy object that would allow me to set a setting which displays application icons only on taskbars where the window is open? Without GPO or registry tweak this can be set by right clicking on taskbar, selecting properties, and then for Windows 10 with multiple displays the setting can be set at the bottom to one of the following: "All taskbars", "Main taskbar and taskbar where window is open", or "Taskbar where window is open". The latter is what I am trying to enforce on workstations via GPO or registry tweak.

I have latest Windows 10 ADM/ADMX files, but can't seem to find a GPO that would let me do that.

Answer (score 5):

After running Process Monitor with registry filter I found out what registry value was changing when different settings were applied.

**Location:** `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

**Value name:** `MMTaskbarMode`

**Value data:** `0-2`

> 0 - All taskbars
>
> 1 - Main taskbar and taskbar where window is open
>
> 2 - Taskbar where window is open